# Object in a 2d array keeps on resetting and I don't know why

Tags: java, oop, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make a tic tac toe game, and it works fine when the first X or O is inputted, but when the second is inputted the previous X or O is deleted and the new one is put in. I have no idea why this is happening.

```
     import java.util.Scanner;
     public class Play {
         public static void main(String[] args){
             Scanner kbd=new Scanner(System.in);
             TicTacToeBoard t=new TicTacToeBoard(3, 3);
             t.startBoard();
             XO xo1=new XO();
             xo1.setTurns(1);
             XO xo2=new XO();
             xo2.setTurns(0);
             System.out.println("Player 1, what is your name?");
             String n1=kbd.nextLine();
             System.out.println("Player 2, what is your name?");
             String n2=kbd.nextLine();
             System.out.println(t);
             while(!t.winner()&&!t.full()){
                 if(t.getTurnCnt()%2==0){
                    System.out.println(n1+"(X): ");
                    int x1=kbd.nextInt();
                    int y1=kbd.nextInt();
                    t.add(x1, y1, xo1);
                    System.out.println(t);
                 }
                 //this is where the board resets
                 else{
                    System.out.println(n2+"(O): ");
                    int x2=kbd.nextInt();
                    int y2=kbd.nextInt();
                    t.add(x2,  y2, xo2);
                    System.out.println(t);
                }
```

TicTacToeBoard Class:

```
     public class TicTacToeBoard extends Board{
         private XO[][] board;
         private int turnCnt;
         public TicTacToeBoard(int r, int c){
             super(r, c);
            board=new XO[r][c];
            turnCnt=0;
        }
        public void startBoard(){
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
                    board[i][j]=new XO();
                    board[i][j].setName("-");
                }
            }
        }
         public void setTurnCnt(int t){
            turnCnt=t;
        }
         public XO[][] setBoard(XO[][] b){
            return b;
        }
         public XO[][] getBoard(){
            return board;
        }
         public int getTurnCnt(){
            return turnCnt;
        }
         public boolean add(int x, int y, XO x1){
            if(x<=this.getRows()&&y<=this.getCols()&&(board[x-1][y-1].getName().equals("-"))){
                 board[x-1][y-1].setName(x1.getName());
                 turnCnt++;
                 return true;
            }
             else
                 System.out.println("error");
                 return false;
        }
         public boolean winner(){
             boolean t=false;
             for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                 if(board[i][0].equals(board[i][1], board[i][2])||board[0][i].equals(board[1][i], board[2][i])||board[0][0].equals(board[1][1], board[2][2])||board[2][0].equals(board[1][1], board[0][2]))
                    t=true;
            }   
             return t;
        }
         public boolean XWinner(){
             boolean t=false;
             for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                 if((board[i][0].equals(board[i][1], board[i][2])&&board[i][1].getName().equals("X"))||(board[0][i].equals(board[1][i], board[2][i])&&board[0][i].getName().equals("X"))||(board[0][0].equals(board[1][1], board[2][2])&&board[0][0].getName().equals("X"))||(board[2][0].equals(board[1][1], board[0][2])&&board[2][0].getName().equals("X")))
                     t=true;
            }
             return t;
        }
         public boolean full(){
             boolean t=true;
             for(int r=0;r<3;r++){
                 for(int c=0;c<3;c++){
                     if(board[r][c].getName()=="-")
                         t=false;
                }
            }
             return t;
        }
         public String toString(){
             return "\t\t\tCol\n\t\t1\t2\t3\nRow\t1\t"+board[0][0]+"\t"+board[0][1]+"\t"+board[0][2]+"\n\t2\t"+board[1][0]+"\t"+board[1][1]+"\t"+board[1][2]+"\n\t3\t"+board[2][0]+"\t"+board[2][1]+"\t"+board[2][2];
        }
    }
```

XO class:

```
    public class XO {
        private String name;
        private int turn;
        public XO(){
            turn=-1;
        }
        public int getTurns(){
            return turn;
        }
        public String getName(){
            if(this.getTurns()==1)
                name="X";
            else if(this.getTurns()==0)
                name="O";
            else
                name="-";
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String n){
            name=n;
        }
        public void setTurns(int t){
            turn=t;
        }
        public boolean equals(XO x1, XO x2){
            if (x1.getName().equals(this.getName())&&x2.getName().equals(this.getName())&&this.getName()!="-")
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        public String toString(){
            return name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you check in your debugger that all the elements in the `board` are different?

Comment: What is your board array made of? Can you add your whole class TicTacToeBoard as well as XO ?

Comment: The problem must be in the `TicTacToeBoard`. You might be resetting the board every time you are doing a `setName`. To know for sure you need to show us your `TicTacToeBoard` class

Comment: I have added both the TicTacToe class and the XO class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on your function

```
public String getName(){
            if(this.getTurns()==1)
                name="X";
            else if(this.getTurns()==0)
                name="O";
            else
                name="-";
            return name;
        }
```

Every time  is called the name field is updated despite it is a getter method! This is not a best practice.

Let's go step by step:

1. the user gives his coordinates.
2. the name is set to the correct value: "X" or "O"
3. the board is printed (calling XO.toString (using name field direct
   no through any getter
4. The status of the board is evaluated using the getName getter and
   now is when the name got back to "-" because the turn has not been
   changed.

Finally, I think that you can simplify XO class. Turn field does not add any worth. It seems enough to use the name field itself. And the if statement is redundant because the boolean expression inside the if is just what you want to return.

```
class XO {

   String name="-";
public void setName(String name){
    this.name=name;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;

}
public boolean equals(XO x1, XO x2){
    return(x1.getName().equals(this.getName())&&x2.getName().equals(this.getName())&&this.getName()!="-");               
}

 @Override
 public String toString() {
     return getName();
 }
```

}

As an example, this can be the final code. Notice that more refactor can be done i.e. use an enum for XO status.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Play {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        TicTacToeBoard t = new TicTacToeBoard(3, 3);
        t.startBoard();
        XO xo1 = new XO();
        xo1.setName("O");
        XO xo2 = new XO();
        xo2.setName("X");
        System.out.println("Player 1, what is your name?");
        String n1 = kbd.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Player 2, what is your name?");
        String n2 = kbd.nextLine();
        System.out.println(t);
        while (!t.winner() && !t.full()) {
            if (t.getTurnCnt() % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println(n1 + "(X): ");
                int x1 = kbd.nextInt();
                int y1 = kbd.nextInt();
                t.add(x1, y1, xo1);
                System.out.println(t);
            }
            //this is where the board resets
            else {
                System.out.println(n2 + "(O): ");
                int x2 = kbd.nextInt();
                int y2 = kbd.nextInt();
                t.add(x2, y2, xo2);
                System.out.println(t);
            }
        }
    }
}
     class TicTacToeBoard {
        private XO[][] board;
        private int turnCnt;
        public TicTacToeBoard(int r, int c){

            board=new XO[r][c];
            turnCnt=0;
        }
        public void startBoard(){
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
                    board[i][j]=new XO();
                    board[i][j].setName("-");
                }
            }
        }
        public void setTurnCnt(int t){
            turnCnt=t;
        }
        public XO[][] setBoard(XO[][] b){
            return b;
        }
        public XO[][] getBoard(){
            return board;
        }
        public int getTurnCnt(){
            return turnCnt;
        }
        public boolean add(int x, int y, XO x1){
            if(x<=this.getRows()&&y<=this.getCols()&&(board[x-1][y-1].getName().equals("-"))){
                board[x-1][y-1].setName(x1.getName());
                turnCnt++;
                return true;
            }
            else
                System.out.println("error");
            return false;
        }
        public boolean winner(){
            boolean t=false;
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                if(board[i][0].equals(board[i][1], board[i][2])||board[0][i].equals(board[1][i], board[2][i])||board[0][0].equals(board[1][1], board[2][2])||board[2][0].equals(board[1][1], board[0][2]))
                    t=true;
            }
            return t;
        }
        public boolean XWinner(){
            boolean t=false;
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                if((board[i][0].equals(board[i][1], board[i][2])&&board[i][1].getName().equals("X"))||(board[0][i].equals(board[1][i], board[2][i])&&board[0][i].getName().equals("X"))||(board[0][0].equals(board[1][1], board[2][2])&&board[0][0].getName().equals("X"))||(board[2][0].equals(board[1][1], board[0][2])&&board[2][0].getName().equals("X")))
                    t=true;
            }
            return t;
        }
        public boolean full(){
            boolean t=true;
            for(int r=0;r<3;r++){
                for(int c=0;c<3;c++){
                    if(board[r][c].getName()=="-")
                        t=false;
                }
            }
            return t;
        }
        public String toString(){
            return "\t\t\tCol\n\t\t1\t2\t3\nRow\t1\t"+board[0][0]+"\t"+board[0][1]+"\t"+board[0][2]+"\n\t2\t"+board[1][0]+"\t"+board[1][1]+"\t"+board[1][2]+"\n\t3\t"+board[2][0]+"\t"+board[2][1]+"\t"+board[2][2];
        }

         public int getRows() {
             return 3;
         }

         public int getCols() {
             return 3;
         }
     }
     class XO {

       String name="-";

        public void setName(String name){
            this.name=name;
        }

        public String getName(){
            return name;

        }
        public boolean equals(XO x1, XO x2){
            return(x1.getName().equals(this.getName())&&x2.getName().equals(this.getName())&&this.getName()!="-");
        }

         @Override
         public String toString() {
             return getName();
         }
     }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)